# GCP GKE: Unable to add GPU to Autopilot - Pod Unschedulable

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I followed the [GCP guide on adding GPU resources to GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/autopilot-gpus), but it doesn't work. There is no error message, no pod logs and a status error in GCP, saying my pod is unschedulable.

I have 1 GPU quota available in the GKE region.

**gpu-pod.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-gpu-pod-1
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator: nvidia-tesla-t4
  containers:
  - name: k8image-sha256-1
    image: eu.gcr.io/gcp-project/k8/k8image@sha256:
    resources:
      limits:
        nvidia.com/gpu: 1
```

I deploy it: `kubectl apply -f gpu-pod.yaml`

And my pod is in a forever pending state:

[image]

For trouble-shooting, I deployed the same pod `my-gpu-pod-2`, without the GPU accelerator, and it's working fine - so there are no issues with the image.

I suspect the GPU node can't be found - but how do I fix that?

Answer (score -1):

**Reproduced your environment:**

1. Created an Autopilot GKE cluster with 2 default nodes
2. Scheduled pod with GPU by following Google Cloud official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/autopilot-gpus)
3. By executing `kubectl describe pod <pod name>` command, observed that the pod was in a pending state due to **node affinity/selector**. Pod has certain affinity rules and cluster does not have node pools which satisfy those rules Unschedulable due to affinity rules or taints.
4. After some time GKE created a new node with GPU capability, once node is running(My pod also scheduled automatically).

**Please wait for 5 to 10 mins till the new node spins up & running. So that the pod will be scheduled automatically as per GKE Autopilot.**(The `nvidia-driver-installer` is downloading Nvidia drivers from Nvidia’s web servers. This may cause additional delay. Check the driver-installer container logs to track progress)

If you still have any issue you can troubleshoot either by executing the following command: `kubectl describe pod <pod name>` and checks the events section **or** In `Console` : Go to `Kubernetes Engine >> Workloads >> WorkloadName and click on the pod` where it shows Unschedulable and go to the Events section of the pod.

**Also check below possible causes for pod unschedulable :**

1. Cluster autoscaler unable to scale up due to IP Range Exhaustion :
   Check you may do not have visibility or control of nodepools, and pods-per- node is fixed at 32 (/26 for each node) it is fairly common for autopilot customers to under-provision IP space for pods, and end up with unschedulable workloads and autoscaling failures. Check logs for IP address exhaustion.
2. Check Pod is requesting for resources which are higher than a node capacity pod that does not fit on a node. Pod may show Unschedulable for insufficient resources despite correct affinity and node capacity
3. Check cluster autoscaler unable to scale up as it hit a quota limit or error Quota limit reached and Cluster autoscaler cannot add more nodes as we reached maximum limit for scale up defined for node pools Max Limit for auto scaling reached

You can tell GKE about the problematic node by using the following command:

```
kubectl drain NODE_NAME --ignore-daemonsets
```

Refer to official Google Cloud documentation on [Troubleshooting Autopilot clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-autopilot-clusters) about causes and how to avoid pods stuck in pending status for more information.

Comment: In my case, step 4 never happens. The pending state is endless. I waited over 24 hours. I think since GKE Autopilot is on the same node, a new, matching node with GPU is just never provisioned.

Comment: what is the output of **kubectl describe pod <pod name>** command?

Comment: Could you please let me know whether you were able to resolve your issue based on the answer & comments, I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Comment: This issue did resolve. I removed the cluster from `eu` and recreated the same on `us-central`. The issue went away and a GPU node was provisioned.

Comment: I am trying to do this in asia-south1 and am getting this issue, how can I fix this ?